# Debugging sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection using Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-7

Is it possible to set up intellij to step into the sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection sources?  When I try and step into a method call I do not even get the class level debugging that I am used to seeing when the source is not available.  Since this is part of the JDK itself do I have to run a different version with debugging enabled?

Comment: The actual bug I hit I filed here (https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/627) but I do not think the bug is in that project.  I think the problem exists in my webapp library (Play 1.2), so I was trying to strip out the retrofit layer (it uses HttpURLConnection underneath the covers) so I could file a bug with Play, but when I tried translating the HttpURLConnection calls by hand it works, so I wanted to see where my hand coded client vs retrofit client differ.